# Spark scala Dataframe isin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Spark Dataframe that contains Array[Byte]. Can I use `isin` for matching data against my `Array[Byte]`? If I try to use it like this:

```
clientIp.isin((whitelist:_*))
```

it does not match as the `whitelist:_*` does not format the byte array to `IN(...)` properly. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you convert the Array[Byte] to list, then can you use that?

Comment: Since https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#isin(scala.collection.Seq) accepts sequence of `java.lang.object`, as long as if you can convert `Array[Byte]` to some form of java.lang.object, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `Array[Byte]` to Java `String`, then you can match this with `isin(whitelist:_*)` if your white list `List<String>`

As per documentation, `isin` method accepts java.lang.object or `Seq(java.lang.object)`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#isin(scala.collection.Seq)

Comment: Well, yes, but I have a lot of data in Array[Byte] and it would be much slow to convert. I would prefer to leave data in bytes and compare bytes

Answer (score 2):

According to the [scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#isin(scala.collection.Seq)), isin method expects varags rather than a Seq[String]. In your case if you convert your data to a Seq[String], you can do the following:

```
df.filter(column_name.isin(seqOfString: _*))
```